# What is the fastest way to access a pixel in QImage?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qimage

I would like to know what is the fastest way to modify a portion of a QImage.

I have this piece of code that has to be executed with a frequency of 30Hz. It displays an image through a sort of keyhole. It is not possible to see the entire image but only a portion inside a circle. The first for-loop erases the previous "keyhole portion displayed" and the second updates the position of the "displayed keyhole".

```
for (int i = (prev_y - r_y); i < (prev_y + r_y); i++){
        QRgb *line = (QRgb *)backgrd->scanLine(i);
        for(int j = (prev_x - r_x); j < (prev_x + r_x) ; j++){
            if((i >= 0 && i < this->backgrd->height()) && (j >= 0 && j < this->backgrd->width()))
                line[j] = qRgb(0,0,0);
        }
    }
    prev_x = new_x; prev_y = new_y;

    for (int i = (new_y - r_y); i < (new_y + r_y); i++){
        QRgb *line = (QRgb *)backgrd->scanLine(i);
        QRgb *line2 = (QRgb *)this->picture->scanLine(i);
        for(int j = (new_x - r_x); j < (new_x + r_x) ; j++){
            if ((((new_x - j)*(new_x - j)/(r_x*r_x) + (new_y - i)*(new_y - i)/(r_y*r_y)) <= 1) && (i >= 0) && (i < this->picture->height())&& (j >= 0) && (j < this->picture->width()))
                line[j] = line2[j];
        }
    }
    this->current_img = this->backgrd;
}
this->update(); //Display QImage* this->current_img
```

If I analyse the timestamps of the program I find a delay in the flow of execution every time it is executed...
Is it so high consuming to access a pixel in a QImage? Am I doing something wrong?
Is there a better alternative to QImage for a Qt program?

Comment: Welcome to per pixel per frame code.  Time to microoptimize.  How many pixels?  Can you move method accesses out of loops?  Move conditions out of loops?  Touch memory in order and **once** only?

Comment: It is a square of about 80x80pixels... but I realized that it is not the size that matters since also with few pixels modification I have the same behaviour.... I will move it in another part of the code...

Comment: time for a http://sscce.org -- details of the inner loop do not matter if they do not make a difference!

Comment: The fastest way is: not doing it at all. Copy a rectangular portion from the source image to a new image, then paint over it to provide the keyhole effect. The raster paint engine will likely be much faster than whatever code you write. The code will be much easier to maintain. If all you do is paint over an image, there's no need to resort to code like you show above.

Comment: you can't improve it anymore. IMO first you should use profiler to make sure that you are optimizing proper code. Attached code for 80x80 size image should run much faster then 30Hz even on ancient machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I understood **it wasn't pixel acces that was slow**, but the rendering.
 During the tests I did I used plain color images, but these kind of images are much faster to render than complex images loaded from file. With other tests I realized was the rendering that was slow.

The fastest way to render an QImage is first of all to transform it using

```
public: static QImage QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(const QImage &img)
```

then the image can be fastly manipulated (it preserves bits() scanline() width() and height() functions)
and can be displayed very fast by openGL (no further conversions are necessary)

```
QPainter painter(this);
glDrawPixels(img.width(), img.height(), GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.bits());
painter.end();
```

Answer (score 1):

How about prerendering your 'keyhole' in an array/qimage and doing a bitwise AND with the source?

- Original pixel && black => black
- Original pixel && white => original pixel

You have a lot of conditions in the innermost loop (some can be moved out though), but the circle radius calculation with the multiplies and divides looks costly. You can reuse the keyhole mask for every frame, so no calculations need be performed.

Answer (score 0):

- You could move some of the conditions at least to the outer loop, and maybe pre-compute some of the terms inside the conditions, though this may be optimized anyway.
- Call update only for the rectangle(s) you modified
- Where do you get the time stamp? Maybe you lose time somewhere else?

Comment: The operations that are time consuming (from the timestamp analysis) are the access to the rows and the pixels. So is this the fastest way to access pixels in Qt? Or there is fastest way?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know the fastest way to access the data of a QImage is to use QImage::bits() which give you direct access to the data of QImage.

For your problem, A better approch will be to do as Bgie suggested : using a array representing the keyhole and doing only a bitwise AND operation.

it will help to choose the correct format for your Image, the format RGB32 and ARG32_Premultiplied_ARGB32 are the fastest. Don't use ARGB32 if you don't need it.

Comment: he used `scanLine()` which is as fast as `bits()`.